# Regex to select all words with missing substring

Tags: regex, search

I'm trying to select all lines that are missing a particular substring. In this case, any line missing the aria-label attribute.

```
<section class="test-class" aria-label="some text">
<section class="test-class" aria-label="">
<section class="test-class">
<section class="test-class" >
<div class="test-class">
```

Desired result:

```
<section class="test-class">
<section class="test-class" >
```

I read some other questions and answers and attempted a negative look ahead, but I think I may have the syntax wrong? I'm trying to utilize this to run a search in my text editor.

[Here's my regex so far](https://regexr.com/3nr40): `/test-class.*?!aria-label/g`

Comment: (?!.*aria-label.*)(<.+>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?!.*aria-label.*)(<.+>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/i0aacp/13/

`<.+>` means match everything between `<` and `>`

Negative lookahead means that a value between `<  &  >` ,A `aria-label`not a part of it.

Your tester link https://regexr.com/3nr4f

Comment: I slightly modified this to be more specific so as to be sure to grab only 'section' elements missing the aria-label https://regexr.com/3ns3m 
Updated question to be more descriptive as the example was bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To syntax for a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is `(?!`

Assuming your string starts with `<` and ends with `>` and you do not have to verify `class="test-class"`:

To match the label your might use `\baria-label="[^"]*"`.

You can use this in a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert that the label does not occur in the string:

[`^(?!.*\baria-label="[^"]*").*$`](https://regex101.com/r/nOT2vj/1/)

**This would match**

- `^` From the beginning of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead that asserts what follows

  - `.*` Any character zero or more times
  - `\baria-label=` Match a wordboundary and aria-label=
  - `"[^"]*"` Match `"`, NOT `"` zero or more times and then `"`
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `.*$` If that assertion is ok, match any charcter zero or more times until the end of the string.

```js
const strings = [
  "<section class=\"test-class\" aria-label=\"some text\">",
  "<section class=\"test-class\" aria-label=\"\">",
  "<section class=\"test-class\" testaria-label=\"\">",
  "<section class=\"test-class\">",
  "<section class=\"test-class\" >"
];

let pattern = /^(?!.*\baria-label="[^"]*").*$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```